# When I use the return back(), I get an error

Tags: php, laravel

I have a modal form in a page pointing to a route that includes an message to a client, and it does all right, but when it is going back to the page I got the message of wrong method :

The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST

The form is :

```
<form action="{{route('incluir_mensagem')}}" method="post">
                
                @csrf
               
                <div class="modal fade" id="staticBackdrop" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                      <div class="modal-header cab-msg">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="staticBackdropLabel">Nova mensagem para : {{$necps->nome_part}}</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                      </div>
                      <div class="modal-body">
                          <div class="texto-oferta">Oferta : {{$ofps->desc_of}}</div>
                          <div class="texto-necessidade">Necessidade : {{$necps->desc_nec}}</div>
                          <br>
                          <textarea name ="mensagem" class="form-control" id="mensagem" rows="3"></textarea>

                          <input value="{{$ofps->id_part}}" name="id_part_t" id="id_part_t" type="hidden">
                          <input value="{{$ofps->id_of_part}}" name="id_of_part_t" id="id_of_part_t" type="hidden">
                          <input value="{{$necps->id_nec_part}}" name="id_nec_part_t" id="id_nec_part_t" type="hidden">
                      </div>
                      <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Sair</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Enviar</button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

              </form>
```

The route is :

```
Route::post('incluir_mens_trans',  [TransacoesController::class,'incluir_mens_trans'])->name('incluir_mensagem');
```

and the controller is :

```
public function incluir_mens_trans(Request $request){

$confere = DB::table('transacoes')->where('id_nec_part', request('id_nec_part_t'))
                                                ->where('id_of_part', request('id_of_part_t'))

                                                ->first();

            if(!$confere) {                                                   

                  $trans = DB::table('transacoes')->insertGetId([
                        'id_nec_part' => request('id_nec_part_t'),
                        'id_of_part' => request('id_of_part_t'),

                        /*Em andamento */
                        'id_st_trans' => 2, 

                        'data_inic' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
                  ]);

                  $id_trans = $trans;

            }else{
                  $id_trans = $confere->id;
            }

            $msgs_i = DB::table('mensagens_trans')->insert([
                  'id_trans' => $id_trans,
                  'mensagem' => request('mensagem'),
                  'data' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
                  
            ]);

            $msgs = DB::table('mensagens_trans')->where('id_trans', $id_trans)
                                                ->select('mensagens_trans.*')
                                                ->orderBy('data','desc')
                                                ->paginate(5);

            return back();
```

Some tip about what is going on?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try to clear all your config with `php artisan optimize:clear`
I cannot reproduce this bug.
Try to tell us the Laravel version if it persists.

Comment: I tried the "php artisan optimize:clear" comand but I still get the same error message. 
My Laravel version is 8 .
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you should just write the method variable as uppercase:

method="POST"
replace this:

```
<form action="{{route('incluir_mensagem')}}" method="post">
```

with this

```
<form action="{{route('incluir_mensagem')}}" method="POST">
```

Comment: thanks but uppercase does not matter in this cases.

Comment: If you did not try yet, I suggest you do it once.

Comment: Yes I tried. but no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change :

```
return back();
```

By :

```
return redirect()->back();
```

Comment: no effect. getting still : 
The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.


I am using laravel 8.

Comment: To avoid this error, I advise you to use: `return redirect()->route('YourRouteName');` or `return redirect('/YourUrlName');`

Comment: already did that. No effect. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like Laravel is trying to navigate back to the Form POST route. You can try redirecting with the route name or route URL:

```php
return redirect()->route('yourRouteName');
```

If you want to send a message back to the client, you can use a syntax like below:

```php
return redirect()->route('yourRouteName')->with('status', 'Profile updated!');
```

Reference:
[HTTP Redirects - Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/redirects#redirecting-named-routes)

Comment: Also tried that but the same message persists :

Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException
The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.

Comment: Try redirecting back to the Form using direct route URL instead of named routes.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem using GET in the form that sent me to the page that is giving the issue. Now I can use the modal that is in this page that point to a function in a controller that uses "return back();" now with no error showing.
But I got a new one.
In this page I have a table showing the records there are the result of the modal inclusion in this table, and there is a paginator that is not working.

```
<div class="pagination">
        {{$msgs->links('layouts.paginationlinks')}}
</div>
```

"$msgs" came from the function that is in the controller like showed above in this Question.
I dont need to resend the $msgs variable because it is already in the page.

The page has the following paramesters that came from the previus GET form :

```
http://localhost:8000/mens_trans_ofertas_part?_token=myYfwIbbHIZhPMiCK7j3EJpej1jHF1tgDcrN48pQ&id_part_t=26&id_nec_part_t=4&id_of_part_t=14
```

But when I use the pagination link, it cames with :

```
http://localhost:8000/mens_trans_ofertas_part?page=2
```

So there is no more parameters neither the token. All desapears!

I used this pagination routines in other pages with no problems.
Can't understand why doenst work now.
:-(